# Is $A$ invertible if $ABAB^2 = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **Q:** Have two matrices of order $5$, $A$ and $B$. If $ABAB^2 = I$, is $A$ invertible?
>
> **A:** Yes, the inverse of $A$ would be $BAB^2$

---

My definition of an inverse matrix is:

For some matrix $X$, its inverse $X^{-1}$ (if it exists) is one such that

$$XX^{-1} = X^{-1}X = I$$
In that case, looking at the question above, there's something that I don't quite get:

Since $ABAB^2 = I$, we know that $A(BAB^2) = I$, which means that $(BAB^2)$ is the inverse of $A$ **from the right**.

However, don't we also have to prove that it is **from the left** as well since matrix product is NOT commutative? That is, $(BAB^2)A = I$? Otherwise, $(BAB^2)$ would not necessarily be $A$'s inverse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for insightful explanation as to why right inverse equals left inverse for square invertible  matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74363/looking-for-insightful-explanation-as-to-why-right-inverse-equals-left-inverse-f)

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i and other questions that are linked there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a theorem that says that if $D$ and $E$ are two square matrices of the same size *such that* $DE = I$, then automatically $ED = I$. Thus an inverse on the right is always an inverse.

This is a major theorem in linear algebra, that will usually be taught in any introductory class. For the reasons you mentioned (non-commutativity), it is not initially clear why it should be true.

Comment: Only of the same size?

Comment: Yes, otherwise they can't be multiplied, since they're square. I'll edit the answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed an important observation. However, there is a theorem which states that for every two square matrices of the same dimension, $A,B$, if $AB=I$ then also $BA=I$.