# Why is it enough to only check if $A\cdot A^{-1} = I$ when showing that $A^{-1}$ is the inverse of A?

Tags: matrices

A matrix A is said to be invertible if there exists a matrix $A^{-1}$ such that $A\cdot A^{-1} = I$.

Given that we find a matrix (call it $A^{-1}$) such that $A\cdot A^{-1} = I$, I'm wondering why it is enough to stop here and not check whether $A^{-1}\cdot A = I$ as well. Any hints?

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/74363/42969.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this statement is true only for square matrices.  It is possible that for non-square matrices that $AB=I$ but $BA\neq I$.  Take for small example $[1~0]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right] = [1]$ which is the $1\times 1$ identity, however changing the order of multiplication does not result in an identity.  Such a situation we might call these "Right inverses" or "Left inverses" of one another.

Comment: @MartinR, I think that is the question.  Why does the first statement imply the second?

Comment: @mjw you ask why $(A,B$ square matrices $AB=I\implies BA=I)$ implies $(AA^{-1}=I\implies A^{-1}A=I)$?  Replace the name $A^{-1}$ with the name $B$ and you are done.

Comment: @JMoravitz, sorry for not being clearer.  Why (for square matrices, of course) does $AB=I \Rightarrow BA=I?$

Comment: @mjw: That is answered in the Q&A that I linked to (as a possible duplicate target)  in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to think about $A$ as a linear operator, say from $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$. By rank-nullity theorem, we know that $A$ is surjective if and only if it is injective, so if $A$ is surjective then it is invertible. Since there exists $B$ such that $AB=I$, $A$ is right invertible and therefore surjective. Thus, $A$ has an inverse and we can easily see that $A^{-1}=B$:

$$B=IB=A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}I=A^{-1}.$$